# Using SQLCMD in a batch file, how can I parse the response and check for an error?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I'm using SQLCMD to get the count of rows in a table, but I also want to be aware if the query hits an error.

The sqlcmd I'm using looks like this:

```
sqlcmd -S %server% -U %user% -P %pass% -b -Q "select count(*) from %table%"
```

If it works, it will return:

```
-----------
      10205

(1 rows affected)
```

(Note, there is a blank line above the ------- for the column name I'm not specifying.)

If I pass in a table that doesn't exist, I get the following response:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server devServer, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.no_table'.
```

Since I have the -b flag, I can check ERRORLEVEL for a value (in this case, 1).

To store the count variable, I've been using the following line:

```
for /F %%i in ('sqlcmd -S %server% -U %user% -P %pass% -b -Q "select count(*) from %table%" ^| findstr /r "[^(][0-9]"') do SET /a rec_count=%%i
```

After the for, %errorlevel% returns 0. Even inside the do, errorlevel is 0.

Is there any simple way to run sqlcmd, store the count if there is not an error, and print both lines if there is an error?

Comment: If this was a new project, I completely agree. Unfortunately, I'm just trying to add a count to an existing batch file.

Comment: I'm assuming you're saying that `errorlevel` is not being changed - even when the table is invalid?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Errorlevel is unchanged if ran in the for loop, but it is changed if ran outside the for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Commands that are executed by FOR /F are implicitly executed via a new CMD session. For example, with `for /f %a in ('echo hello') do ...`, the command that is executed becomes `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c echo hello`.

Your command is properly setting the ERRORLEVEL, but then the value is lost as soon as the child CMD session terminates and control is returned to your batch script.

So the `/b` option is not really doing any good for you, and can be dropped.

You can suppress the header info by adding the `-h -1` option.

You can suppress the `(1 rows affected)` message by prefixing your command with `set nocount on;`

You can add the `-r 1` option to cause error messages to appear on stderr instead of stdout. This will prevent FOR /F from processing any error, and the error message will appear on the screen instead.

You can clear the rec_count variable before you execute the command. Then it will remain undefined if there was an error, else it will contain the count if there was no error.

```
set "rec_count="
for /f %%A in (
  'sqlcmd -S %server% -U %user% -P %pass% -h -1 -r 1 -Q "set nocount on;select count(*) from %table%"'
) do set "rec_count=%%A"
if not defined rec_count echo There was an error!
```

One other thing you might consider is using environment variables recognized by SQLCMD for your server, username, and password. Then you won't have to use the -S, -U, or -P options. This is especially handy if your batch script runs many SQLCMD commands.

```
set "sqlcmdServer=YourServer"
set "sqlcmdUser=YourUserName"
set "sqlcmdPassword=YourPassword"

set "rec_count="
for /f %%A in (
  'sqlcmd -h -1 -r 1 -Q "set nocount on;select count(*) from %table%"'
) do set "rec_count=%%A"
if not defined rec_count echo There was an error!
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `errorlevel` does not seem to be getting set is because the `for` command is executing successfully, regardless of how the code that it loops through executes. So you can only interact with the errorlevel that is set by the sqlcmd command on the same line (inside the for loop brackets).

You should be able to use `||` (double pipe) after the sqlcmd command. Any code after `||` will only run if the previous command fails. Example:

```
notACommand || echo test
```

Will return "`test`". While the following will output only "`a command`":

```
echo a command || echo test
```

I can't test it, but something like the following should work for you:

```
for /F "EOL=(" %%i in ('sqlcmd -S %server% -U %user% -P %pass% -b -Q "select count(*) from %table%" ^|^| echo fail') do (
    SET rec_count=%%i
)
if "%rec_count%"=="fail" echo SQL command failed
```

If the output is exactly as you say, then you should not need the findstr command - just set `(` open bracket as an EOL character in the for loop, so you effectively drop the "`(1 rows affected)`" line. You will probably want to use the variables differently, but this is just one way you can tell if the sqlcmd command has failed or not.

As for outputting the error - a bad solution is to run the same sqlcmd command again. Something like the following:

```
set command=sqlcmd -S %server% -U %user% -P %pass% -b -Q "select count(*) from %table%"

for /F "EOL=(" %%i in ('%command% ^|^| echo fail') do SET rec_count=%%i

if "%rec_count%"=="fail" (%command%) else echo rec_count is %rec_count%
```

Note that I removed the /a switch when setting the rec_count variable, because it can now be set as a word.